# How to enter variable in docker image with executable app?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand ENTRYPOINT and CMD fundamentals in (and) Docker.
Have a simple Go script that adds two number, one scaned from CLI. Here is code:

```
func main() {
    x := 0
    fmt.Scanln(&x)
    fmt.Println(x + 3)
}
```

and have simple Dockerfile

```
FROM golang as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o abrakadabra .
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /app/abrakadabra /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/abrakadabra"]
```

Is it posible to make docker image so to be able to enter the number for this go script when image starts or runs? or there must be some simulation of linux in image like busybox?
Most of Docker basic examples considers some kind of servers or databases, I did not find solution for this.

Comment: Read this https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-bash-command-after-startup/21631/2

Comment: Did not find answer there.